# Wrong visual plot representation of a correlation

Tags: r, ggplot2, correlation

I built this code to check the correlation between Bitcoin and other altCoins, the table data is working fine, my only issue is when I try to plot the result to get a visual representation, I get the below result:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyquant)
library(timetk)
library(tibbletime)
library(corrr)

symbols <- c("BTC-USD","ETH-USD","TRX-USD","EOS-USD","ADA-USD")

prices <- getSymbols(symbols, 
                     src = 'yahoo', 
                     from = "2019-09-01",
                     to = "2020-03-24",
                     auto.assign = TRUE, 
                     warnings = FALSE) %>% 
  map(~Ad(get(.))) %>% 
  reduce(merge) %>%
  `colnames<-`(symbols)

prices_monthly <- to.monthly(prices, indexAt = "last", OHLC = FALSE)

prices_monthly %>% correlate() %>% focus('BTC-USD') %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = rowname, y = 'BTC-USD')) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  ylab("Correlation with BTC-USD") +
  xlab("Variable")
```

[Plot result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNRDl.png)

What did I did wrong, please?

Comment: Try backticks, ``, not normal ticks ''.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need backticks around the variable name.

```
prices_monthly %>% correlate() %>% focus('BTC-USD') %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = rowname, y=`BTC-USD`)) +  # <- Here
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  ylab("Correlation with BTC-USD") +
  xlab("Variable")
```

[image]